# Java, XSLT: How to handle the dynamic namespaces generated by Axis in XSLT

Tags: java, xslt

I have an application that calls a web service (axis based) to get a response in the following format:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
    <soapenv:Body>
        <axis2ns394:ServiceLevelDetailsResponse xmlns:axis2ns394="urn:myco:com:mapping:service:3.0">
            <ns1:errorFlag xmlns:ns1="urn:myco:com:mapping:service:3.0">false</ns1:errorFlag>
            <axis2ns394:customerProgram>
                <axis2ns394:name>ABC</axis2ns394:name>
                <axis2ns394:description>ABC SERVICES</axis2ns394:description>
                <axis2ns394:programRank>1</axis2ns394:programRank>
                <axis2ns394:bindOptions>
                    <axis2ns394:name>PRO1A</axis2ns394:name>
                    <axis2ns394:description>Complete Home Solution</axis2ns394:description>
                    <axis2ns394:programName>PROMO</axis2ns394:programName>
                    <axis2ns394:programDescription>Promotional Bundle 1A</axis2ns394:programDescription>
                </axis2ns394:bindOptions>
                <axis2ns394:bindOptions>
                    <axis2ns394:name>PRO2A</axis2ns394:name>
                    <axis2ns394:description>Buy 1 Get 1 Free</axis2ns394:description>
                    <axis2ns394:programName>PROMO</axis2ns394:programName>
                    <axis2ns394:programDescription>Promotional Bundle 2A</axis2ns394:programDescription>
                </axis2ns394:bindOptions>
            </axis2ns394:customerProgram>
        </axis2ns394:ServiceLevelDetailsResponse>
    </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

Here - the namespace 'axis2ns394' is generated dynamically at the runtime. I need to write an XSLT to flatten this XML to a simpler XML (Say one html table with one row for each 'customerProgram'). But I am not sure how to handle these dynamic namespaces.

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Regards,
- Ashish

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Is the *namespace* dynamic, or the namespace ***prefix*** dynamic?

The actual namespace for the XML is **`urn:myco:com:mapping:service:3.0`**

So, an example stylesheet to transform the results doesn't need to know what the namespace *prefix* is, but what the *Namespace* is.  You can use a different namespace prefix in your XSLT and it will match on the elements, as long as you declare the *namespace* correctly.

For example this stylesheet declaring the namespace *prefix* **myco** for the *namespace* **urn:myco:com:mapping:service:3.0**:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
xmlns:myco="urn:myco:com:mapping:service:3.0"
>

<xsl:template match="/">
<table border="1">
<thead>
<tr>
 <th>Name</th>
 <th>Description</th>
 <th>Program Rank</th>
</tr>
</thead>
  <xsl:apply-templates select="//myco:customerProgram" />
</table>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="myco:customerProgram">
<tr>
  <td>
   <xsl:value-of select="myco:name" />
  </td>
 <td>
   <xsl:value-of select="myco:description" />
  </td>
 <td>
   <xsl:value-of select="myco:programRank" />
  </td>

</tr>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Would produce:

```
<table border="1">
<thead>
<tr>
<th>Name</th>
<th>Description</th>
<th>Program Rank</th>
</tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
<tr>
<td>ABC</td>
<td>ABC SERVICES</td>
<td>1</td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: +1 - it's common misconception about what the xmlns attributes actually do

Comment: As you correctly pointed out. The namespace 'prefix' is dynamic. 
Thanks for the solution - its worked likea charm.